# why bimolecular elimination reactions are stereospecific?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]I know the mechanism of this reaction but it is stated that these are stereospecific in nature . why do we call these stereospecific explain with example.

Comment: The hydrogen being abstracted by the base, and the leaving group must be anti-periplanar. This requirement determines the stereochemistry unambiguously , and thus the reaction is stereospecific.